# Flutter [ DataTable ]

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable

Sou novo na programação Flutter. Montei uma pagina que ao chamar via menu gostaria de apresentar os dados em uma DataTable.

Até consegui fazer isto, porém só apresenta os dados quando clico para mudar a ordem, ou seja deveria apresentar os dados logo ao abrir a tela.

Vou postar aqui como montei, se puderem dar uma força. Agradeço desde já!

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:cibernetica/screens/modelDiscip.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cibernetica/screens/loginuser.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class pagdisciplina extends StatefulWidget {
var oTbAluno;
pagdisciplina({this.oTbAluno});

@override
_pagdisciplinaState createState() => _pagdisciplinaState();
}

class _pagdisciplinaState extends State<pagdisciplina> {
var id = ModelDiscip.id;
List<ModelDiscip> tbDiscip;
bool sort;

@override
void initState() {
sort = false;

setState(() {
  var tbtmp = getDisciplina(id);
  tbDiscip = getConvert(tbtmp);
});
super.initState();
}

onSortColum(int columnIndex, bool ascending) {
if (columnIndex == 0) {
if (ascending) {
setState(() {
tbDiscip.sort((a, b) => a.disciplina.compareTo(b.disciplina));
});
} else {
setState(() {
tbDiscip.sort((a, b) => b.disciplina.compareTo(a.disciplina));
});
}
}
}

DataTable dataBody() {
return DataTable(
sortAscending: sort,
sortColumnIndex: 0,
columns: [
DataColumn(
label: Text("Disciplina"),
numeric: false,
tooltip: "Nome da disciplina",
onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) {
setState(() {
sort = !sort;
});
onSortColum(columnIndex, ascending);
}),
DataColumn(
label: Text("Professor"),
numeric: false,
tooltip: "Professor da disciplina")
],
rows: tbDiscip
.map(
// ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
(ModelDiscip) => DataRow(cells: [
DataCell(Text(ModelDiscip.disciplina), onTap: () {
print('Selecionado ${ModelDiscip.disciplina}');
}),
DataCell(
Text(ModelDiscip.professor),
),
]),
)
.toList(),
);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: Text('Disciplinas'),
),
body: Column(
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
children: <Widget>[
Center(
child: dataBody(),
)
],
),
);
}

listaTrabalhos() {
return ListView.builder(
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
return ListTile(
title: Text(''),
);
},
);
}

static Future<List<dynamic>> getDisciplina(int id) async {
String url =
'http://facbrasil.com/mobile/educacional/trabalho/' + id.toString();
final response = await http.get(
url,
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
);
var convDataToJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
List<dynamic> listaDiscip = new List<dynamic>();

for (Map<String, dynamic> json in convDataToJson) {
  ModelDiscip lista = ModelDiscip.fromJson(json);
  listaDiscip.add(lista);
}
return listaDiscip;
}

List<ModelDiscip> getConvert(Future<List<dynamic>> oLista) {
List<ModelDiscip> listConvert = [];
oLista.then((value) =>
{if (value != null) value.forEach((item) => listConvert.add(item))});
return listConvert == null ? [] : listConvert;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não faz sentido chamar `setState` dentro de `initState`, pois o estado só é construído depois que o `initState` acaba, e o `setState` serve para "avisar" ao Flutter que o estado mudou (como ele pode ter mudado se nem foi construído ainda?).

Agora, vamos falar da função `getConvert`: ela é síncrona, então ela retorna *antes* de a função `then`, que retorna uma future, ser computada de fato. Logo, no momento do retorno de `getConvert`, a lista `listConvert` é sempre vazia... Recomendo fortemente que você estude com calma o tutorial sobre [programação assíncrona](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) do Dart, pois não é algo fácil para iniciantes.

O que você quer é esperar que a função passada para o `then` seja executada antes de `getConvert` acabar. Então, você precisa usar o `await` e mudar o retorno de `getConvert` para `Future<List<ModelDiscip>>`:

```
Future<List<ModelDiscip>> getConvert(Future<List<dynamic>> oLista) async {
List<ModelDiscip> listConvert = [];
await oLista.then((value) =>
{if (value != null) value.forEach((item) => listConvert.add(item))});
return listConvert == null ? [] : listConvert;
}
```

Ainda tem outra questão: executar uma função *assíncrona* assim que a tela abre. Para isso, pode-se usar a função [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html). O `initState` ficaria assim (repare no `await` antes de `getConvert`, que retorna uma future):

```
@override
void initState() {
    sort = false;
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
        var tbtmp = getDisciplina(id);
        tbDiscip = await getConvert(tbtmp);
    });
    super.initState();
}
```

Finalmente, umas dicas de estilo: não abuse do `var` e nem de nomes de variáveis abreviados; eles dificultam bastante a leitura. Um exemplo é a linha `var tbtmp = getDisciplina(id);`: não tem como saber o que é `tbtmp` sem sair fuçando o resto do código.

Comment: Josenaldo, boa noite. Obrigado pelo retorno e pelas dicas. Vou fazer esses ajustes que pontuou e respondo assim que finalizar os ajustes.